# Value of type List(Of Long) cannot be converted to List(Of ListItem)

Tags: vb.net, list

I am filling data from `removeActiveService` (list of listItem) into a new list `listRemove`. However `listRemove` is turning into a list of Long.

```
Dim listRemove = removeActiveService.Select(Function(item) item.Text.Replace(serviceRemove, "") And item.Text.Split("-"c)(0).Trim And item.Value.Split("-"c)(1).Trim).ToList()
```

If I change it to `Dim listRemove As List(Of ListItem)`, it results in the error

> Value of type List(Of Long) cannot be converted to List(Of ListItem)

I need to perform replace and split on the text and value (see my code). What is the correct syntax here so that it can be a List(Of ListItem)?

---

EDIT

1. Starting with checkboxlist items in `removeActiveService`
2. Copy that into a brand new list of items called `listRemove`.
3. I need to perform these on the TEXT of the list items in `listRemove`

- item.Text.Replace(serviceRemove, "")
- item.Text.Split("-"c)(0).Trim

4. And I need to perform this on the VALUE of the list items in `listRemove`

- item.Value.Split("-"c)(1).Trim

Comment: Why would you be using `And` there? That is a Boolean or bitwise operator. Do you want to perform a Boolean or bitwise operation there? I think not. Please explain in detail what it is that you want to do with an item, including an example or two of potential inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: @user18387401 For each item, I need to replace the text, split the text and grab the left half, and split the value and grab the right half. (See code). I was using And to combine these functions. How can I do it instead of And?

Comment: Telling us to "see code" isn't helpful when the code makes no sense. No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Edit your question and provide the FULL and CLEAR explanation that you should have in the first place, including the examples I asked for. I can see that you want to perform three separate operations but there's little indication of what you want to do with those three results, because using `And` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect to output a `List(Of ListItem)` then you need to create `ListItem` objects somewhere, which you're not doing now. You're performing operations on the input data but you're not doing anything useful with the results. `And` doesn't do anything that could be considered useful there. If you expect to output a list of `ListItem` objects containing the results of those operations then you actually have to create `ListItem` objects containing the result of those operations. As far as I can tell, this would be the way to go:

```vb
Dim listRemove = removeActiveService.Select(Function(item) New ListItem With
                                                           {
                                                               .Text = item.Text.Replace(serviceRemove, "").Split("-"c)(0).Trim(),
                                                               .Value = item.Value.Split("-"c)(1).Trim()
                                                           }).
                                     ToList()
```